# Enabling payments with a credit card in PayPal gives crash on both simulator and physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

```
 _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = NO;
```

If I set `_payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards` to YES, the app crashes with the following exception:

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <PayPalPaymentViewController: 0x7f8b03029a00
```

Comment: what do you want to say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do import

```
#import "CardIO.h"
```

In your ViewController.h file and also add `CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate`
in your class.